Seeking confirmation or advice on best way to retrieve all transactions associated with a specific account for a given block
I need to retrieve all signatures on a given block for a given account. I'm using the RC branch right now, and think it will be likely that v2 will be the release branch by the time I'm ready to deploy.
I notice that getBlock (and its siblings) don't have the ability to filter transactions based on an account. Likewise, getSignaturesForAddress doesn't have the ability to filter by slot - only by signature (before and until).
I could obviously getBlock and then filter transactions - but that seems weighty, so I'm hoping there's something better.
I wonder if I can rely on the ordering of transactions returned by getBlock, and use the first and last transaction's signatures as the constraints on getSignaturesForAddress.
I'm not really sure if it will work, and have come here hoping for confirmation or refutation, as well as anything I may have missed that will make this task as efficient as possible.
Thank you for any help.

Unfortunately, without additional indexing or info, your best bet will be to filter through everything in getBlock. As you point out, the only other option is to use the before and until parameters in getSignaturesForAddress.
